# ComboBox in Gtk2hs compiling error

Tags: haskell, combobox, gtk2hs

How can I handle a ComboBox with Gtk2hs? 
On [this](https://github.com/gtk2hs/gtk2hs/blob/master/docs/tutorial/tutorial.t2t#L271) page I found a solution:

```
store <- listStoreNew ["green", "yellow", "..."]
comboElem <- comboBoxNewWithModel store
ren <- cellRendererTextNew
cellLayoutPackEnd comboElem ren True
cellLayoutSetAttributes comboElem ren store
  (\txt -> [cellText := Just txt])
```

However while compiling I get this error (which occurs in the last line of my code example):

```
Main.hs:36:17:
No instance for (System.Glib.UTFString.GlibString (Maybe [Char]))
  arising from a use of ‘cellText’
In the first argument of ‘(:=)’, namely ‘cellText’
In the expression: cellText := Just txt
In the expression: [cellText := Just txt]
```

How can I fix the problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GlibString`](https://github.com/gtk2hs/gtk2hs/blob/master/glib/System/Glib/UTFString.hs#L119) Doesn't appear to have an instance for `Maybe String`. It may have at one point, but you should be able to just use `cellText := txt` instead. If for whatever reason you need to use a `Maybe String`, you could implement the instance yourself.

Comment: It's probably more that the property type of `cellText` has at some point (in some Gtk2HS version) changed from `GlibString a => Maybe a` to `GlibString a => a`.